# Laravel Query - Count and filter

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with this query: I Want to count how many logs there are in the last 24h from a specific user, and with a specific status_code (example 400)".

Actually, with this query, I found all logs from a specific company.

```
  $webhookLog = WebhookLog::where('company_id', $company->id)
->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: what is your problem with the query? Could you give us more info?

Comment: try $webhookLog = WebhookLog::where('company_id', $company->id)
->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(1))
->where('status_code',400)
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

Answer (score 0):

In controller

in function

```
  $date = date('Y-m-d');
  $webhookLog = WebhookLog::where('company_id', $company->id)
  ->whereBetween('updated_at, [$date . " 00:00:00", $date . " 23:59:59"])
  ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
```

this will return todays logs

replace get() with count() to get the count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method for from date for 24 hours

```
$fromDate = Carbon::now()->subMinutes(1440);
$toDate = Carbon::now();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
$webhookLog = WebhookLog::query()
        ->where([
            ['company_id', '=',$company->id],
            ['user_id', '=', Auth::id()],
            ['status_code','=',400]
        ])
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [
                Carbon::now()->subHours(24),
                Carbon::now()
            ])
        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
```